# Printing of initials without "." as the last character

Tags: c, string-parsing

So I want to make a program in C which prints the initals of a name but facing one problem . My program should not print `.` as the last character, and I have tried this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    printf("Enter your Name : \n");
    char name[25];
    gets(name);
    int i;
    printf("%c.",name[0]);
    for(i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(name[i]==' '){
            printf("%c",name[i+1]);
            if(i<strlen(name)){
                printf(".");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but while running this program the with example input `Satyajit Kumar Ghosh`, it is giving output "S.K.G." I am not getting why it is printing "." at the end as I give the condition

```c
if(i<strlen(name)
```

Comment: shouldn't `"S.K.G."` be the correct output? What output are you expecting instead?

Comment: Why do you think `if (i < strlen(name))` will stop a period being put after the last initial? It only checks whether you're before the end of the string, not whether you're at the last word. Also, you really should calculate that `strlen()` just once outside the loop, to ensure it doesn't waste cycles doing it every iteration, then loop to that instead of `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program should be as below. You were printing dot after character while detecting white space, so code added last dot after G instead before it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    printf("Enter your Name : \n");
    char name[25];
    gets(name);
    int i;
    printf("%c",name[0]);
    for(i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(name[i]==' '){
            printf(".");
            printf("%c",name[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition checking (i < strlen(name)) doesn't do quite the job. By the time the iterative variable *i* reaches the position of character 'G', *i*'s value was only 15 (which is clearly passes the condition checking).

From what I infered, you expected the result to be S.K.G instead. My suggestion is that you print the first initial separately, and then for every following initials, you print out the '.%c'. So the code should look like this:

```
// Assuming there is at least a word
printf("%c", name[0]);
for(i=1;name[i]!='\0';i++){
    if(name[i]==' '){
        printf(".%c",name[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be approaching this backwards.  You're printing the next character followed by a '.' every time you run into a ' ' (space).  That means, when you run into the space between Kumar and Ghosh, it'll say print 'G' followed by '.'.

You could try storing the last character you came across either from the beginning of the string or after the last space and then print it fololowed by a '.' if you come across another space or null '\0' character.

Answer (score 0):

When your `i` arrives G from Ghosh it is way behind the end of the string. When you call the last if statement i is in your example at 15. But your String is longer. This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    printf("Enter your Name : \n");
    char name[25];
    gets(name);
    int i;
    printf("%c",name[0]);
    for(i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(name[i]==' '){

            printf(".%c",name[i+1]);
        
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```